# UTF-8 and mymysql package

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using the [mymysql](http://godoc.org/github.com/ziutek/mymysql) to insert records into a MySQL DB in Go.

I am attempting to insert UTF-8 encoded data into a table. If I insert the data directly using the mysql command prompt, it works fine. If I use mymysql, `L’ Échafaud` becomes `Lâ€™ Ã‰chafaud`.

It was my understanding that mymysql uses UTF-8 by default. Just in case I added the explicit `db.Register("set names utf8")` but that hasn't helped either.

If I print the strings to screen before inserting them, they appear to be encoded correctly.

Is there something else I need to do in Go to insert UTF-8 encoded strings?

Here are the relevant code sections:

```
func NewDbConnection(dbName string, dbServer string, dbUser string, dbPass string) (*Db, error) {
    me := Db{}
    me.Conn = mysql.New("tcp", "", dbServer, dbUser, dbPass, dbName)
    err := me.Conn.Connect()
    me.Conn.Register("set names utf8")
    return &me, err
}

func (db *Db) InsertRelease(r Release) (uint64, error) {
    stmt, err := db.Conn.Prepare(`insert into releases
        (name,artist_id,itunes_id,genre,label_name,image_source,
        created_at,updated_at,date,scraped,itunes)
        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,true,?)`)

    res, err := stmt.Run(r.Name, r.ArtistID, r.ItunesID, r.Genre, r.LabelName,
        r.ImageURL, r.CreatedAt, r.UpdatedAt, r.ReleaseDate, r.ItunesURL)
    return res.InsertId(), err
}

type Release struct {
    ID, ArtistID, ItunesID, ArtistItunesID, Type int
    Name, ImageURL, Genre, LabelName             string
    ItunesURL                                    string
    ReleaseDate, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt            time.Time
}
```

Comment: Just in case: can you connect to the DB and issue a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableHere\G` ? This should have a `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` at the end.

Comment: Would it be worth including your code here to rule out any problems from that side?

Comment: Confirmed that `SHOW CREATE` output ends with: `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=176375 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: How do you issue the read command which returns mangled characters ? from go code ? or from a mysql command prompt ?

Comment: Mangled characters from MySQL command prompt, but it is also mangled in the UTF-8 rendering Rails app that the DB is powering.

Comment: Looking again at the question it seems to me that the values are properly written as utf-8, but than *read* as latin-1. So the fault might not be in the place where the insert happens, but where the data is read from the database. (Also the mysql commandline can use a different encoding than the database,that would explain why the charactes show mangled up there.)

Comment: I don't believe this to be the case unless the same field can be read in different encodings in a result array of Ruby's ActiveRecord. This was my first suspicion too.